# hide input values based on selected option in dropdown, ng-repeat ng-hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Without JQuery I'd like to be able to hide certain form input fields when a selection is made in the `<select>` drop down menu.

Similar to [this behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/C4AEN/2/), but with ng-repeat. And a little more dynamic, making ng-hide use some sort of isHidden function calling the ng.models attributes, comparing to the selected value

Here's my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/Td2NZ/260/, with the ng-hide being `ng-hide="address.state === 'FL'"`

the `=== FL` part is hardcoding "FL", but I'd like that to draw from the input that is being repeated in ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Td2NZ/261/

A couple things to note: the way to determine if something is hidden should be a property of the input to be hidden, not the select menu option. You had an attribute in the drop down `affects: xxx`, now that is an attribute of the input: `hiddenBy: xxx`. Also to hide the label as well the `ng-hide` has been moved to the `<div>` tag. This should get you started. Another resource that helped solve this problem was http://plnkr.co/edit/SxIvt4KThWLtWvh3PnOh?p=preview

The JSFiddle you provided almost works, if you want it to work with hardcoded "FL" change `===` to `==`.
`===` checks type and value, where you really want to just check value is equal. It is best practice to always use `===`, but in this scenario you should use `==`.

#### angular

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.addresses = [
    {'state': 'AL'},
    {'state': 'CA'},
    {'state': 'FL'}
];

$scope.lov_state = [
    {'lookupCode': 'AL', 'description': 'Alabama'},
    {'lookupCode': 'FL', 'description': 'Florida'},
    {'lookupCode': 'CA', 'description': 'California'},
    {'lookupCode': 'DE', 'description': 'Delaware', 'affects': 'hidden'}
];
$scope.inputs_text = [
        {label: "Start Date", input:'yyyy-mm-dd', name:'dat_start', isRequired: "true"},
        {label: "End Date", input:'yyyy-mm-dd', name:'dat_end', isRequired: "true"},
    {label: "hide_for_FL", input:'wow', name:'hidden', isRequired: "true", hiddenBy: 'FL'}
        ];
$scope.isHidden = function(){
    return message = (address.state === 'FL');
};
});
```

#### html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div>Billing State:
        <select ng-model="address.state" ng-options="state.lookupCode as state.description for state in lov_state" ng-init="address.state=1"></select>
        <p> address.state: {{address.state}}</p>

    </div>
     <br> <tt>State selected: {{address.state}}</tt>
    <div ng-repeat="input in inputs_text" ng-hide="(input.hiddenBy == address.state)">
        <label>{{input.label}}</label>
        <input name="{{input.name}}" id="{{input.name}}" ng-model="input.input" ng-require="input.isRequired"></input> <!-- function -- find address.state in the array, when match found get affects option and if it equals input.input return true -->
        <p> Input: {{input.input}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```